# Data structure in C programming

Tags: c, search, data-structures, linked-list

i was asked to create employee record using linked list to insert five different employee .then,display all employee record and lastly search by employee number.i made a mistake to write write search function by employee name.another thing is even in search by employee by name when it found it it some time at below it say employee not found.this two problem anyone can help.any to change search function by  employee name to by employee number.Please help.

this is what i have so far.tell me what i need to change

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node* createnode(struct node*);
void display(struct node*);
void search(struct node*);

struct node
{
int emp_num;
char name[10];
int Year_service;
float salary;

struct node* ptr;
};

int main()
{
struct node* head;
int b,i;

head=NULL;

while(1)
{

printf("\n1-> to enter the employee details\n2->to display All employee details\n3->to search an element\nEnter the value\n");

scanf("%d",&b);

switch(b)
{
case (1): printf("\nEnter the Number of Employee's Detail you would like to enter\n");
          scanf("%d",&i);
   while(i>0)
   {
   head=createnode(head);
   i--;
   }
   break;

case (2): display(head);
          break;

case (3): search(head);
          break; 
default :
printf("\nEnter Valid Choice \n");

}
}
}


void display(struct node* head)
{
if(head==NULL)
{
printf("\nThe list is empty \n");
}

else
{
while(head!=NULL)
{
printf("*****************************************************");
printf("\nThe employee Number :%d\n",head->emp_num);
printf("\nThe Employee Name :  %s\n",head->name);
printf("\nThe Salary : %f\n",head->salary);
printf("\n Years  serviced : %d\n",head->Year_service);


head=head->ptr;

}

}
}

struct node* createnode(struct node* head)
{

struct node* newnode;
newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof (struct node));

printf("\nEnter the  employee number \n");
scanf("%d",&newnode->emp_num);
printf("\nEnter the employee name \n");
scanf("%s",newnode->name);
printf("\nEnter the salary of the employee \n");
scanf("%f",&newnode->salary);
printf("\nEnter the Employee Years of service \n");
scanf("%d",&newnode->Year_service);

if(newnode == NULL)
{

newnode->ptr=NULL;
}

else
{
newnode->ptr=head;


}
return newnode;
}


void search(struct node* head)
{
char ch[10];

printf("\nEnter Employee Name\n");

scanf("%s",ch);


while(head!=NULL)
{
if(strcmp (ch,head->name)==0)
{
printf("\nThe element is matched\n");
printf("\nThe  employee Number : %d\n",head->emp_num);
printf("\nThe  employee name : %s\n",head->name);
printf("\nSalary : %f\n",head->salary);
printf("\nYears serviced : %d\n",head->Year_service);
}

else {
printf("\nThe element is not matched\n");
}
head=head->ptr;
}


}
```

Comment: We are not a code nor homework writing service. Please [edit] your answer to specifically point out your problem and not dump your whole code. If you create a [mcve] you'll probably find the solution yourself (and an [mvce] is advised in questions!)

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable that indicates the item was found. It will then be used to display if the element has not been found.

```
void search(struct node* head)
{
    char ch[10];

    printf("\nEnter Employee Name\n");
    scanf("%s", ch);

    int element_found = 0;

    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(ch,head->name)==0)
        {
            printf("\nThe element is matched\n");
            printf("\nThe  employee Number : %d\n",head->emp_num);
            printf("\nThe  employee name : %s\n",head->name);
            printf("\nSalary : %f\n",head->salary);
            printf("\nYears serviced : %d\n",head->Year_service);
            element_found=1;
        }
        head=head->ptr;
    }

    if(!element_found)
    {
        printf("\nThe element is not matched\n");
    }
}
```